# Finding line of intersection of two planes

Tags: analytic-geometry

When an equation of line is given as intersection of two planes like $$ax + by + cz + d = 0 = px + qy + rz + s,$$ why do we put $z=0$?

Comment: Maybe because $z$ serves as a parameter, that is, $z=t$ for any real number $t$, in particular, we can take $z=0$.